# Select next/previous item & bring it to front in fabric js

Tags: vue.js, fabricjs

Imagine we have 10 items on canvas. I need to implement `next` and `previous` buttons.

When I click next, if there is an active object, next object should be selected and brought to front, so that the user could easily click on the item and move it.

However in fabricJs all layers represented as array of objects. When I bring object to front, it changes its index. So, for example, we have 3 items:

```
1 // currently selected
2 
3
```

Then I set 2 item active and bring it to front. The array now becomes:

```
2 // currently selected and brought to top
1
3
```

Then if I select next item it will be 1, not 3.

Here is example code:

```
selectNextItem() {
  let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject()

  if (!activeObject) {
    return false
  }

  let totalObjectsNumber = this.canvas.getObjects().length
  let currentIndex = this.canvas.getObjects().indexOf(activeObject)
  let nextIndex = null

  // We reached the last item, rewind to the beginning
  if (currentIndex === totalObjectsNumber - 1) {
    nextIndex = 0
  } else {
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
  }

  let object = this.canvas.item(nextIndex)
  this.canvas.setActiveObject(object)
  object.bringToFront() // <--- this causes problem

  this.canvas.renderAll()
}
```

So I understand what's wrong but couldn't figure out how to solve it. In any graphical editor if I select next layer it won't be brought to top. If I brought it to top, I cannot continue this action, and select next layer and bring it to top too.

I use fabric in combo with vueJs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your function I it works fine for me using Fabricjs 2.3.3. What version are you using?

```js
 var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');


 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#000",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        strokeWidth: 10  
    });
    
  var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    fill:  "#FF0FF0",
    stroke: "#AABBCC",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    strokeWidth: 10     
  }); 
  var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 75,
    top: 75,
    fill:  "#CCCFF0",
    stroke: "#DDBBFF",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    strokeWidth: 10  
  });

canvas.add(rect,rect2,rect3);
console.log(canvas.getObjects());

setInterval(function(){
 selectNextItem();
},1500);

function selectNextItem() {
 console.log('Select NEXT Item');
  let activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject()

  if (!activeObject) {
    return false
  }

  let totalObjectsNumber = canvas.getObjects().length
  let currentIndex = canvas.getObjects().indexOf(activeObject)
  let nextIndex = null

  // We reached the last item, rewind to the beginning
  if (currentIndex === totalObjectsNumber - 1) {
    nextIndex = 0
  } else {
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
  }

  let object = canvas.item(nextIndex)
  canvas.setActiveObject(object)
  object.bringToFront() // <--- this causes problem
  canvas.renderAll()
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>React Redux Webpack ToDo App</title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please select an object and see the result. Please let me know if it is a right behavior.